# Python convention for passing in a file path, file name, or file object

Tags: python

I often see Python code that accepts a variety of inputs...

file names

```
s = Something("/Users/me/my_file.txt")
```

file paths

```
s = Something("my_file.txt")
```

or file objects

```
f = open("my_file.txt", "r")
s = Something(f)
```

Is there a convention to this?
As a lot of people mentioned, it depends on what `something()` is. What situations are better suited to file names vs. file objects?

I wonder if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692663/how-to-accept-file-or-path-as-arguments-to-method-in-python) SO post gives the best answer.

Comment: It depends on what `something()` is doing, whether it is checking the type of argument being passed or not.

Comment: Almost everywhere, a bare file name "foo" is treated identically to the more explicit path "./foo", so there's really only two cases: paths and objects.

Answer (score 4):

The [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) has two methods for loading data: `json.load` which takes a file-like object, and `json.loads` which takes a string:

```
>>> json.load(open("my_file.json"))
[1, 2]
>>> json.loads("[1, 2]")
[1, 2]
```

The [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#usage) module has a similar interface (one accepts a file-object, and a second which takes a string)

Essentially, your API primarily uses file-objects, and you provide a convenience method which wraps the supplied-string in a [`StringIO` object](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html). Might look something like this:

```
class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self, fh):
        # Can do things like:
        first_line = fh.readline()
        fh.seek(0)
        all_content = fh.read()


def parse(fh):
    return Parser(fh)


def parse_str(inputstring):
    fh = StringIO.StringIO(inputstring)
    return Parser(fh)
```

Comment: Perhaps the conventionn is to design two interfaces and let the user decide what type the are passing in, calling the appropriate method, rather than give them one interface and check the type behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2):

That all depends on the interface of `Something()`. I don't know if it's fair to say that there's one strict convention for this. The nice part about duck typing is that you don't need to know the type of arguments to a function, only certain ways in which the arguments behave.

Comment: Good question, I guess I'm thinking abstractly at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It don't think there is any applicable convention.  It totally depends on what your program wants to achieve.